# getline() is repeatedly reading the first line of my file

Tags: c++, getline

I don't know if anyone will see this in time, but I'll try...
I am in an introductory c++ class (undergrad) and I have an assignment due for monday morning...(YES! I know I have procrastinated :), )

Ok. I have to read in student records in this form:

```
Adriana,Smith,692493955,50,43,52,86,74,83
Adrienne,Johnson,480562092,75,72,93,71,81,89
Bla, Bla, Bla
```

from a file (up to 200)and sort them and stuff.

I have managed to make all other necessary functions, but can't verify them.

I made a function that is supposed to open the file, read in each line and within each line read in each token and store them in a temporary array. This tempArr[9] goes and gets validated before getting put into the real array[9][200].

I have managed to open the file, read in the first line and tokenize it into an array, but when the while loop reiterates, it again reads in the first line of the file, thus when I print out the real array I get +/-200 times the first record.

I read and reread my manual, getline() info on cplusplus.com, searched in forums and switched my code around a million times.

PLEEEEAAASSSSEEE HELP!

Here's the fn:

```
void getFile(std::string realArray[][200], const int ROW_SIZE)
{
    std::string filename, token, line;

    int positionLine(0);
    int positionToken(0);
    int row(0);
    int numOfLine(0);
    const int ROWS (9);
    const int MAX_RECORDS (200);
    std::string tempArray[ROWS];

    std::cout << "Please enter the desired filename with it's extension:\t ";
    std::cin  >> filename;

    const char *file=filename.c_str();
    std::ifstream input(file, std::ios::in);

    while (!input.is_open())
    {
        std::cout <<    "The file did not open correctly. \n\nPlease enter a valid filename.\n";
        std::cin  >> filename;

        const char *file=filename.c_str();
        std::ifstream input(file, std::ios::in);
    }

    while (input.good() && numOfLine < MAX_RECORDS)
    {
        getline (input,line);
        std::istringstream inputss (line);

        while (getline(inputss, token, ',') && row < ROWS )
        {
            tempArray[row] = token; 

            row++;
        }
        numOfLine++;

        validateData (tempArray,ROWS , numOfLine);

        storeData(tempArray, ROWS, realArray, ROW_SIZE, numOfLine);

    }

    if (numOfLine == MAX_RECORDS)
    {
    std::cout << "The maximum number of records to be read (" << MAX_RECORDS << ") has been reached.\n";
    }

}
```

PS I'm working on visual studio 2010
and my file is *.dos

Oh, and I took out

using namespace std;

because it was giving : cout is ambiguous error.

THANKS
N.

Comment: It doesn't show above, but there is a \n before the second record. i.e. each record is on a separate line.

Comment: To format code, indent it by 4 spaces. :)

Comment: Your compiler will be giving you warnings about variables hiding other variables. You should listen to it.

Comment: although I can't see where your file reading issue is, I can tell you about the `using namespace std` line.  If you add `using namespace std;`, you would write a cout like `cout<<"stuff";` and not `std::cout<<"stuff";`.

Comment: BTW, and easy way to see if your call to `getline()` isn't working is to directly output `line` right after the call to `getline()`.  So i.e., do something like `std::cerr << line << endl;` immediately afterwards.  Don't do `std::cout` since that buffers and may not output immediately when called. That way to can see if you're actually reading the data you've intended. As I mentioned in my answer, I don't think you're having any problems with `getline()` at all, and your real issues are further down the line.  Debug code like the one I mentioned will help you isolate the problem-spots quicker.

Comment: @prelic - a `using namespace std` will also pull in thousands of names, causing potential name conflicts. Nothing a beginner needs!

Answer (score 3):

Where to start!!!!

Bad practice. One per line!

```
std::string filename, token, line;
```

These are un-used. Delete them.

```
int positionLine(0);
int positionToken(0);
```

Don't extract a pointer to a string into a new variable.
If filename is altered then file becomes invalid.
It is only safe to use when the result is passed into a function.

```
const char *file=filename.c_str();
std::ifstream input(file, std::ios::in);
```

Thus you should do it like this.

```
std::ifstream input(file.c_str());
```

Here. You are declaring a completely new variable `input`. This variable has nothing to do with the other variable `input`. This version is destroyed when it goes out of scope at the end of the while loop.

```
while (!input.is_open())
{
    // <STUFF DELETED>
    std::ifstream input(file, std::ios::in);
}
```

This is a very common mistake.
Testing for the good state here is (usually) wrong. This is because the normaly you want the loop to exit when you hit the end of file. But the last read actually reads up-to but not past the end of file and thus it does not trigger the EOF flag and the loop is re-entered. Then the next read will fail:

```
while (input.good() && numOfLine < MAX_RECORDS)
{
    getline (input,line);
```

The better version is:

```
while (getline (input,line) && numOfLine < MAX_RECORDS)
{
```

Here you get it correct:

```
    while (getline(inputss, token, ',') && row < ROWS )
    {
```

Here you incrementing row to index into `tempArray`. But I see no where that row is reset to 0.

```
        tempArray[row] = token; 
        row++;
```

#### Edit:

Based on Bo's commoents below.

Technically there is nothing wrong with doing:

```
const char *file=filename.c_str();
std::ifstream input(file, std::ios::in);
```

Here the `file` is used immediately and never used again. From experience though I find that by doing this you have introduced a new variable into the context that other feel free to re-use. Normally this is not a problem but this particular pointer can invisibly become invalid (if the filename object is modified then the file pointer can potentially become invalid).

This is a maintenance problem and is particularly dangerous when you have multiple developers modifying the code. If the variable `file` is re-used later in the code by developer 'A' and developer 'B' then comes along and addes code that modifies variable `filename` now you are in a situation that can be dangerous.

Thus it is always safer **NOT** to store pointers that can become *invisibly* invalid. Thus the only safe way to use them is as a parameters to functions.

```
std::ifstream input(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in);
```

Another situation that I came across recently was the same problem in a slightly different context:

```
QString   path(<Some String>);
char*     file = path.toLatin1().data();
readFile(file);
```

The problem here is that toLatin() returns an object of QByteArray. This object is returned by value and not assigned to any variable and thus is a temporary. Temporary objects are destroyed at the end of the expression so the method data() that returned a pointer to an internal part of the QByteArray has assigned to the variable `file` a value that is invalid as soon as the ';' is hit.

The safe way to do this was to pass the result directly as a parameter to the function:

```
readFile(path.toLatin1().data());
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in doing things step by step, like getting a pointer to the file name on one line and using it on the next. Perfectly good code!

Comment: @Bo Persson: In this case there is no danger. But I find it leads to problems when maintaining the code. You now have this extra pointer variable that can become invalid without your knowledge and could be used later in the code. If you want to bring it out into a seprate variable you should be careful to limit its scope that it can not be used accidentally latter in the code.

Comment: well, just for your pleasure, @Martin, I took out the pointer and did as you wrote, just to make sure. It gets pretty confusing when a whole bunch of different people say a whole bunch of different things... I'm trying to get better... (I've got a long ways to go...) anyway, I changed pretty much everything that people told me: @Xeo indent 4 spaces, hi hi... etc. But I do rather use the getline out of while loop and put it at the end to make sure eof is noticed and last line not copied. I still have a problem but nothing to do with getline... So Thanks All!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're not re-setting the value of `row` ... therefore when you increment row and it exceeds the value of `ROWS`, you stop storing any new values inside of `tempArray`.  So you're reading the file just fine from `getline()`, but you're not storing those new values in tempArray to be validated once `row >= ROWS`.

Resetting the value of `row` should do the trick.  You also may want to, depending on how your `validateData()` function works, pass it the value of `row` rather than `ROWS` so that you don't get data stored from the previous loop mixing in with the data read on the current loop if `getline(inputss, token, ',')` returns an error and bails before you've read `ROWS` amount of data.

Hope this helps,

Jason

Comment: Well, thanks for answering @Jason, but it didn't work. I reset row after validateData fn call and I passed row to it in stead but I still get an array full of Adrianna Smith's...

Comment: @prelic - yeah, I know about that. It was fine in compiling my code until all of a sudden it was giving me "cout is ambiguous" and I read on a web site that it's bette

Comment: better to always use std::whatever and that noobs would figure out why in the future... :)

Comment: @johnsyweb - ummm I would really love to know what you mean. :)

Comment: @Natlie ... when you add `std::cerr << line << endl;` right after the call to `getline()` is the output matching the lines of the file you're reading from?  If so, then the problem is not your call to `getline()`.

Comment: ... this thing keeps entering my comments without my approval ... :) sorry 'bout the multiples. By the way anyone know how to include a sort.cpp in my main.cpp? I incuded the sort.h but it wont understand the fn call...

Comment: AHHHHHhhhhhhh Jackpot! it's entering the right stuff!!! hmmm then it has to do with the strings I'm giving to my array... Am confused...

Comment: would I have to reset my array as well?

Comment: Sorry, for you code make that `std:cerr << line << std::endl;`

Comment: You mean `tempArray`? You shouldn't need to ... every time you copy `token` into `tempArray[row]` it should re-initialize the string to the value you're passing in using the `operator=()` member function of `std::string`.  What else did you change that it started working?

Comment: yeah! got that by myself ;)   I guess I have to look at my functions and see what else might be wrong... THANKS SOOOO MUCH though @Jason. I probably have a logical error somewhere else. will try to find it myself but at least now I'm not looking at something that isn't the problem... :)   AM happy

Comment: no no it doesnt work. its just that I know its not the getline.

Comment: BTW, just compiled you code and input a sample data file ... you don't need to reinitialize `tempArray` ... the data seems to be written just fine.

Comment: One more thing.  I would change your while-loop code so that you init `line` using `getline()` right before you enter the while-loop, and then do the `getline()` in the while-loop as the last line of the while-loop right before re-checking the loop guards.  That way you won't get a double-read of the last data-element in the file, because right now `getline()` can return an error for EOF, but you'll still use the last set of data inside of `tempArray` from the previous loop since the loop guard isn't checked immediately after doing `getline()`, and so you get an extra iteration of your loop.

Comment: ok, will do. BTW I just tried sending the validateData fn so you could see maybe if you wanted to what it does but it doesnt fit in the comment box. lol

Comment: Oh, and you wouldn't happen to know how to include another .cpp file in the main.cpp?

Comment: Yes ... simply do `#include MyCppFile.cpp` ... buy why are you doing that?  That's really not suggested.  If you are defining a bunch of functions, classes, etc., make a header file, and just include the header file to access those additional functions.  Also if you haven't placed `#define` guards on any header files you've made, and you double them up in your .cpp file by doing an `#include XXXX.cpp` that also includes those headers, you're going to get a bunch of compiler errors for multiple definitions if you have structs, classes, etc. defined in those headers.

Comment: I don't know, it's my teacher who wants two of our functions (sort and search) to be in separate .cpp and .h files. So I have my main .cpp, which includes the header file for all my fns. then I have to make a sort.cpp, sort.h and search.cpp, search.h So I #include" sort.h" in sort.cpp and #include sort.cpp in main.cpp? Or do I have to do that + #include "Debug\sort.h" in my main.cpp as well???

Comment: no, I always put the #define, but when I try to do #include sort.cpp it doesn't work, #include <sort.cpp> doesn't either nor does #include"sort.cpp" and the only thing that works is #include "Debug\sort.h" but then the fn sort turns grey in sort.h and my main can't access it...

Comment: Nope, nope, make a sort.h with the function declaration for the function defined in sort.cpp, a search.h with the function declaration for the function defined in search.cpp, and then inside your main.cpp just include sort.h and search.h to access the functions.  There is no need to include search.cpp and sort.cpp in your main.cpp.  You may want to ask your teacher how the compiler and linker work together and allow you to make a call from main.cpp to a function defined in a different .cpp file without having to directly included the source-code in your main.cpp.

Comment: yeah I did that all. and I sort of get how they "communicate with each other" hi hi but is #include"Degub\sort.h" OK, 'cause I don't think so, but it wont accept #include "sort.h" so, ???

Comment: Ha, you were right... it tells me : error C2084: function 'void sort(std::string [][200],const int)' already has a body (bla bla bla): see previous definition of 'sort'

Comment: DON'T DEFINE FN'S TWICE, I get it...sorry. Done commenting.